# help for convergence of an integral

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

Does this integral converges:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm e^{ -\mathrm{i}\omega t}}{\sqrt{(-1)^\frac{1}{3}(\mathrm{i}\omega)^\frac{4}{3}}}\,\mathrm{d}\omega$$
and why ?

Comment: You might want to explain the meanings of $(-1)^{1/3}$, $i^{4/3}$ and the square root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral converges.  Ignore the imaginary factors and rewrite the rest as

$$e^{-i 2 \pi/3} \int_0^{\infty} d\omega \: \omega^{-2/3} \, e^{i \omega t} + \int_0^{\infty} d\omega \: \omega^{-2/3} \, e^{-i \omega t}$$

The first integral comes from the substitution $\omega \leftarrow -\omega$.

For both integrals, the singularity at $\omega=0$ is integrable.  The question is the behavior at $\infty$. Consider the first integral: substitute $\omega = u^3$ and get, neglecting the complex factor again:

$$3 \int_0^{\infty} du \: e^{i t u^3}$$

To see how this integral converges, consider the integral in the complex plane

$$\oint_c dz \: e^{i t z^3}$$

where $C$ is a wedge-shaped contour with 3 pieces: 1) along the real axis, 2) a circular arc subtending an angle of $\pi/6$ into the first quadrant, and 3) a line back to the origin.  By Cauchy's theorem, this integral is zero.  Also, one may show that the integral over the circular arc is zero when $t >0$. Then we get

$$\int_0^{\infty} du \: e^{i t u^3} = e^{i \pi/6} \int_0^{\infty} dy \ e^{-t y^3} $$

Because the second integral clearly converges, the first integral does; therefore

$$\int_0^{\infty} d\omega \: \omega^{-2/3} \, e^{i \omega t}$$

converges when $t>0$.

The second integral

$$\int_0^{\infty} d\omega \: \omega^{-2/3} \, e^{-i \omega t}$$

may be shown to converge similarly for $t>0$ by using $C$, but flipped to be below the real axis.  Also, for $t<0$, just flip the contours about the real axis.

**ADDENDUM**

Over the circular arc of radius R, let $z=R e^{i \phi}$, $\phi \in [0,\pi/6]$.  Then the integral over the arc is

$$i R \int_0^{\pi/6} d\phi \: e^{i \phi} e^{i t R^3 (\cos{3 \phi} + i \sin{3 \phi})} = i R \int_0^{\pi/6} d\phi \: e^{-t R^3 \sin{3 \phi}} e^{i \phi} e^{i t R^3 \cos{3 \phi}}$$

Over the integration interval, $\sin{3 \phi} \ge 0$ and the integral on the right converges for $t>0$ as $R \to \infty$. To show that the expression on the right vanishes in this limit, consider that the integral is dominated by contributions near $\phi=0$; this the expression behaves as, worst-case:

$$R \int_0^{\pi/6} d\phi \: e^{-t R^3 \sin{3 \phi}} \sim R \int_0^{\infty} d\phi \: e^{-3 t R^3 \phi} = \frac{1}{3 R^2 t} \quad (R \to \infty)$$

Comment: *one may show that the integral over the circular arc is zero*... You might want to add details about this step of the proof.

Comment: @did: see the addendum.  Thanks for mentioning it - I'm never precisely sure how much detail is the right amount to make the solution clear without making it unreadable.

Comment: Two quibbles: you forgot the "dz" term; and one must show that $R\times$ the last integral you wrote goes to zero when $R\to\infty$ (which is true but requires an additional argument).

Comment: @did: I would be a poorer contributor without your eagle eye; thanks again.

Comment: +1 from me. A final note: one can simplify the last argument (and replace the semi-convincing appeal to "domination" and the $\sim$ sign, by stone-hard inequalities) using the fact that $\sin3\phi\geqslant6\phi/\pi$ on the interval of interest.

Comment: @did: thanks again, and I will be sure to adopt that argument next time.  I am so thoroughly ingrained with Bender & Orszag's textbook (or at least my memory of how to do local asymptotic analysis), so the $\sim$ stuff is like falling off a log for me.